# Check if a string is empty or not using Ajax, HTML and PHP

Tags: php, html, angularjs, ajax

I am populating a HTML table with data from ajax as follows:

...

```
                    <td>{{data.ordered}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.quantity}}</td>
                    <td >{{data.pending}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.unit_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.material_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.service_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.cost}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.net}}</td>
```

...

I need to check if a value is empty using PHP.
As example, I am assigning the value of {{data.material_number}} to a variable:

```
<?php $material = '{{data.material_number}}'; echo "Material=".$material;?>
```

The echo shows the value as it should be.

But I need to detect when {{data.material_number}} is empty or has no value, and using the function:

```
strlen($material)
```

it always shows the value 24 when the string is supposed to be empty, but also when the variable is not empty and has a specific value.

How can I check if the variable $material or {{data.material_number}} is empty?

Comment: You wouldn't using Ajax, HTML, and PHP.   Just PHP.   It looks like you're mixing PHP with a templating engine and that is your issue. `$material = '{{data.material_number}}';` isn't going to resolve correctly in PHP.

Comment: the .val() Method should work. Are you using jQuery to?

Comment: @Devon, I need to check it in order to put or not a button on the cell.

Comment: @mvasco I don't really know how to better explain it.  You're not using appropriate calls for PHP.

Comment: This is just a string: `'{{data.material_number}}'`.  It will *always* be exactly the length that it is.  An empty string, by contrast, would be this: `''`.  Whatever `{{data.material_number}}` is (AngularJS?  some templating engine?  something else?), it has nothing to do with the PHP code you're showing.  There's also no AJAX in your question, at all.  So it's really not clear what you're trying to accomplish here.  What is the actual value that you're trying to examine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by David, you can't check a template string with php.  It doesn't work that way.

You could use the template engine to check if it's blank by using a conditional statement on the page.

Using Twig for example:

```
{% if data.material_number is empty %}
<td>0</td>
{% else %}
<td>{{data.material_number}}<td>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks @ja408, is it easy to implement Twig? I will  check it right now.

Comment: What are you using now?  the curly braces typically indicate the use of some template engine.  i.e. Angular, Twig, something else.  I only used Twig syntax as an example, because Twig uses curly braces "{}"

Comment: It is Angular. I am calling a JS file that retrieves the data from a PHP file and then show them on the HTML table

Comment: Thanks, I guess it must be the solution using ng-if

Comment: @mvasco - for the love of god, if you have a question about angular put angular in the tags don't make us all guess.. when you don't use the right tags youre just wasting everyones time.

Answer (score 1):

"empty" is kind of vague.

You could use `empty($variable)` which will return true if `$variable` is null, an empty string, an empty array, the number zero, or if the variable doesn't exist.

You could use `isset($variable)` which will return true if the variable has been set no matter what the value is or false if it doesn't exist.

If you want to check if it's simply an empty string just do `if($variable === ""){ ... }`

---

While that answers your actual question, strlen will also work just fine for your purposes. If it's returning 24 every time it's because your variable is 24 chars every time. period. it's not a bug in PHP, your variable just isn't what you think it is. There must be an issue with your code, but you haven't posted enough of it, so unless you do no one is going to be able to give you a solution.

Comment: Thank you @Pamblam, I will check other ways to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the function `empty()`

For more details, read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: strlen would work fine in this (in question).  The function isn't the issue.

Comment: Yes, you are right Devon, but how can I check if {{data.material_number}} has no value?

Comment: @mvasco `{{data.material_number}}` isn't a PHP variable so you can't using PHP.  You are mixing languages/constructs.

Comment: Understood @Davon, but there must be a way to check it. I need you to explain me how to check if the variable {{data.material_number}}, that is shown correctly in the table is empty or null or whatever, when it shows nothing, I would like to add a button there.

Comment: Thank you @Manikiran, I will check other ways to solve my issue.